# Extract integers from a string (as an int not a list)

Tags: python

I am trying to extract an integer from a string. I have been successful in doing so using various methods however the output is always a list. I can guarantee that the string will only contain one integer and I need manipulate that integer later.

```
import re
string = '123 Hi there!'
number = re.findall('[0-9]+', string)
print number
>>> ['123']

2 * number
>>> ['123', '123']
```

I would like the output of the below to be 246.

Comment: you can do `s * int(number[0])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add a short text to your code, just change this line:-

```
number = re.findall('[0-9]+', string)
```

To this line

```
number = int(re.findall('[0-9]+', string)[0])
```

To get the first element of the list.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

Choose the 0th element to get the string of integer and convert it to integer.

```
number = int(re.findall('[0-9]+', string)[0])
```

Then you can do

```
2 * number
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should solve your problem:

```
import re
string1 = '123 Hi there!'
result = int(re.search(r'\d+', string1).group())
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
import re
string = '123 Hi there!'
number = int(re.findall('[0-9]+', string)[0])
print(number * 2)
```

Here I've used the indexing operator to select the only element in the returned list, and then you just need to convert it to an integer (`int`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search` if you are certain you only have one element.

**Ex:**

```
import re
string = '123 Hi there!'
number = re.search('[0-9]+', string)
if number:
    print int(number.group())*2
```

**Output:**

```
246
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try re.sub

> ```
> sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>     Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
>     non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
>     replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
>     if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
>     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
>     a replacement string to be used.
> ```

That is,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '123 Hi there!'
>>> re.sub("[^0-9]","",string)
'123'
```